# Ionic firstore get specific data of collection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching data from firestore but stuck at one place. I need to fetch specific data which value is equal to doc collection. Please see image

[image]

As you see i have categoryID inside a doc. So i need all doc which have this value in their doc. Any fast solution how can i do this ?

This is my simple code i am fetching all questions by this but need to fech by categoryID

```
  public getQuestions(): Observable<{}[]> {
    return this.angularFirestore.collection("questions").valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries and https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query for example:

```
public getQuestions(): Observable<{}[]> {
return this.angularFirestore.collection("questions", ref => ref.where('categoryID', '==', id_here)).valueChanges();
}
```

Check here for more info about angularfire:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md